# is it possible to separate my admin section from regular web site without creating another web app project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I built my web application using asp.net mvc3.  I need to add admin pages to monitor and manage all user accounts and their posts.

Right now, admin and regular web site are sitting in the same web application.  if I only made a small change for the admin pages, i still need to compile everything.  is it a way separate them, so I only need to upload admin without touching the web site.  the only solution I can  think of is to create another web app.  is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your mvc application into Areas
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx
Areas help you better organize your application it won't let deploy just that area, but VS2010 does have some good deployment features. Her's a good article
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx

Comment: this is what I have right now.  I guess it is teh best solution.